# How to get id number of file system watcher is deleted?

Tags: c#, filesystemwatcher

**Main Code:**

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        MySqlConnection mcon = new MySqlConnection("connection credentials...");
        MySqlDataReader myreader = null;
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("select * from files", mcon);
        mcon.Open();

        myreader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        //List of path's from MySQL table
        List<String> list = new List<String>();

        while (myreader.Read())
        {
            //Appending the list of all path names from MySQL table
            list.Add(myreader[1].ToString());
            //Retrieving id number of path from MySQL table (see list before 'private static void directoryChange')
            list2.Add(myreader.GetInt32(0));


        }
        mcon.Close();

        //This watches all path's listed in MySQL table
        foreach (string i in list)
        {

            Console.WriteLine(i);
            FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
            watcher.Path = Path.GetDirectoryName($@"{i}"); //get specific files listed in MySQL table
            watcher.Filter = Path.GetFileName($@"{i}");
            watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
            watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = true;

            watcher.Created += directoryChange;
            watcher.Deleted += directoryChange;
            watcher.Renamed += onRename;
        }

        Console.Read();
    }

    //List of Id numbers from MySQL table
    static List<int> list2 = new List<int>();

    private static void directoryChange(object source, System.IO.FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
                if (e.ChangeType == System.IO.WatcherChangeTypes.Deleted){
                Console.WriteLine($"Deleted {e.FullPath}"); //Here I need to get the id number of file that has been deleted
                 }
    }
```

**Goal:**

My goal is to get the `id` number from MySQL of the file that has been deleted.

- The file system watches only files listed from MySQL table.
- But how can I print the id number of the record that has just deleted? within the directoryChange?

**Update:**

This is where I got to now:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    MySqlConnection mcon = new MySqlConnection("connection credentials...");
    MySqlDataReader myreader = null;
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("select * from files", mcon);
    mcon.Open();

    myreader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    //List of path's from MySQL table
    List<String> list = new List<String>();
   //List of Id numbers from MySQL table
   static List<int> list2 = new List<int>();

    while (myreader.Read())
    {
        //Appending the list of all path names from MySQL table
        list.Add(myreader[1].ToString());
        //Retrieving id number of path from MySQL table (see list before 'private static void directoryChange')
        list2.Add(myreader.GetInt32(0));


    }
    mcon.Close();

    //This watches all path's listed in MySQL table
        var data = list.Zip(list2, (n, w) => new {Path= n, ID = w});

        foreach(var nw in data)
        {
            int result = nw.ID;
            FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
            watcher.Path = Path.GetDirectoryName($@"{nw.Path}");
            watcher.Filter = Path.GetFileName($@"{nw.Path}");
            watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
            watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = true;

            watcher.Created += directoryChange;
            watcher.Deleted += directoryChange;
            watcher.Renamed += onRename;
        }

    Console.Read();
}
//Tried passing over the id from for loop
static int result;



private static void directoryChange(object source, System.IO.FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
            if (e.ChangeType == System.IO.WatcherChangeTypes.Deleted){
            Console.WriteLine($"Deleted {e.FullPath}"); 
            Console.WriteLine(result);
             }
}
```

This does not work, because result shows as `0`. Will see if I can fix this.

Comment: Maybe I can help you out with this - Instead of having a loop `foreach(string i in list){...}` try using `zip` to join the 2 lists together. You'll get a combined output like so: `{id: 0, path = g:\username...}`

Comment: @LV98 how would I pass the `id` that has just been deleted to the event handler?

Answer (score 1):

So to recap what I parsed from your code:

- You read a list of files from a SQL table
- You initialize a FileSystemWatcher on the directory of each file, with a filter on the name of each file
- You bind all event listeners of all watchers to the same handlers
- In the handler, where you only get the full path to the file you're being alerted about, you want to know the "id" (i.e. primary key of the table) for the given path

So, simply keep a dictionary with the data around instead of two lists or a single static variable?

```
// Class-level field
private static Dictionary<string, int> fileList = new Dictionary<string, int>();

// Then while reading the data:
while (myreader.Read())
{       
    // Use path as a key to the id, so you can use the path later to look up the key
    fileList[myreader[1].ToString()] = myreader.GetInt32(0);
}

foreach(var nw in fileList)
{
    // ...
}
```

And then in your event handler:

```
private static void directoryChange(object source, System.IO.FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ChangeType == System.IO.WatcherChangeTypes.Deleted)
    {
        if (fileList.TryGetValue(e.FullPath, out var id))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(id);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Path '{e.FullPath}' not present in dictionary?");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I see, let me try again. I did not move it inside the whole loop. I declared it before

Comment: shouldn't the fileList be like this: `fileList.Add(myreader[1].ToString(), myreader.GetInt32(0));` instead of `fileList[myreader[1].ToString()] = myreader.GetInt32(0);`?

Comment: Why do you think so?

Comment: Using your code. Gave me a lot of errors. I placed the `private static fileList = new Dictionary<string, int>();` above `static void Main(string[] args)` that gave me errors and placing the `fileList[myreader[1].ToString()] = myreader.GetInt32(0);` inside `Reader` also gave me errors.

Comment: Yeah I missed a type there. It's `private static Dictionary<string, int> fileList = new Dictionary<string, int>();`.

Comment: Now it makes sense.. Need to work on my C# -_-.. where did you learn it? And how long for?